# How to recover category names which are not part of the master list?

Tags: python, outlook, categories

I am trying to recover the list of categories related to a specific email account.

I've been able to recover the list of the master categories.

For my other two mail accounts (a shared one, and another personal one), it's not giving me back the related categories, but instead the same list as the master one.

My code is looping over the listed emails in Outlook, defining the default folder, and supposedly listing the categories related to each default folder.

```
Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
Accounts= win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.Accounts
folders = []

for account in Accounts:  
 
folders.append(list(Outlook.Folders.Item(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName).Folders))
    recipient =Outlook.CreateRecipient(Outlook.Folders.Item(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName))

    inbox = Outlook.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient , 6)
    print(list(inbox.Session.categories))
```

I'm using Python 3.6, and Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can access shared mailbox with the following code, you just have to change "1" until you reach the right shared mailbox

```
main_account = outlook.Folders.item(1)
print (main_account.Name)
for folder in main_account.Folders:
    print (folder.Name)
```